# How to insert value substring-before last '(' after tokenize with ',' in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to insert value `subring-before` last `'('` after `tokenize` `start-with, '('`. I have try both  substring-before (e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(current-grouping-key(), '('), .)"/>`) `'('` or `replace` function  `<p><xsl:value-of select="concat(replace(substring-before(current-grouping-key(), ','), '^([0-9]+)|(\(.*\))(\(([a-z0-9])\))', '$1$2'), .)"/></p>`.
**Input XML**

```
<root>
<p>17200(b)(2), (4)–(6), (8), (12), (16), (20), and (21)</p>
<p>1(a), (b), (c)</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>2</p>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
    <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-by=".">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(current-grouping-key(), ', ')">
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(current-grouping-key(), ', and |, ')">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '(')">
                                <p><xsl:value-of select="concat(replace(substring-before(current-grouping-key(), ','), '^([0-9]+)|(\(.*\))(\(([a-z0-9])\))', '$1$2'), .)"/></p>
                                <!--<p><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(current-grouping-key(), '('), .)"/></p>-->
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></p>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected Output**

```
   <root>
   <p>17200(b)(2)</p>
   <p>17200(b)(4)–(6)</p>
   <p>17200(b)(8)</p>
   <p>17200(b)(12)</p>
   <p>17200(b)(16)</p>
   <p>17200(b)(20)</p>
   <p>17200(b)(21)</p>
   <p>1(a)</p>
   <p>1(b)</p>
   <p>1(c)</p>
   <p>2</p>
</root>
```

**CODE:** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the you seem to simply want to concatenate any characters in the first token before the last `(` to the tokenized value:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-by=".">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(current-grouping-key(), ', ')">
                    <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(current-grouping-key(), ', and |, ')"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$tokens">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of
                              select="if (starts-with(., '('))
                                      then replace(head($tokens), '(.*)\(.*?\)$', '$1') || .
                                      else ."/>
                        </p>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <p><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></p>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfj/33

Comment: Sir, Thanks for the reply but after `tokenize` `17200(b)` missing `(b)` (e.g. `17200(4)–(6)` s/b `17200(b)(4)–(6)`) substring-before s/b last '(' e.g. 17200(b)(2),.

Comment: @Sandy, right, it seems I missed that part of the problem. Check whether the new version does what you want.